SwiftUI subscriptions not working as expected with Combine
Here's my code where the subscription is not working when storing in the AnyCancellable set:
import Foundation
import Combine

class MortgageModel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: - Published Properties (Data Model)

    @Published public var homeValue: Double = 500_000
    @Published public var downPaymentPercentage: Double = 3.5 / 100
    @Published public var isDownPaymentDollarAmount = false
    @Published public var downPaymentDollarAmount: Double = 0
    @Published public var interestRate: Double? = 0.0
    @Published public var loanTerm: Int = 30
    @Published public var startDate = Date().startOfNextMonth
    @Published public var propertyTax: Double = 5000
    @Published public var pmiRate: Double = 1.5
    @Published public var homeInsurance: Double = 968 / 12
    @Published public var monthlyHOA: Double = 0
    @Published public var otherInsurance: Double = 0

    // MARK: - Internal State and Computed Properties

    @Published public var _loanAmount: Double = 0.0
    @Published public var calculatedMonthlyPayment: Double = 0.0

    // MARK: - Combine Logic

    private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        Publishers.Merge3($homeValue, $downPaymentDollarAmount, $downPaymentPercentage)
            .map { [weak self] _ in
                guard let self = self else { return 0 }
                if self.isDownPaymentDollarAmount {
                    return Double(Double(self.homeValue - self.downPaymentDollarAmount))
                } else {
                    return Double(self.homeValue * (1 - self.downPaymentPercentage / 100))
                }
            }
            .assign(to: &$_loanAmount) 
            .store(in: &subscriptions) // error: Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'store'
    }
}

I think I've used .store correctly but Xcode is telling me it's not right.
Any idea what I am doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Remove store. You don’t use that with assign

Certainly! assign(to:) already handles the subscription lifecycle, you can simplify your code by removing the .store(in: &subscriptions).
Checkout:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)

Just remove the .store(in: &subscriptions) 
Reason
Actually, there are 2 versions of assign operator in Combine, which is sometimes confusing.

The version you are using (.store(in: &subscriptions)) doesn't need to be stored in the Cancellable note that you are sending the reference &$_loanAmount. Combine takes care of its Cancellable by itself, so you don't need to store it in another Cancellable. Check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)

Another version assign(to:on:) needs to be stored in the Cancellable. here you don't send the reference in its usage. Check the documentation and usage: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:on:)


